# Is there a Linq Entity Framework query for using an inner join AND an IN() statement?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have found working linq for inner joins and In statements but can not get the two to behave together. Can this SQL statement be converted into Linq?

```
SELECT * FROM Card
INNER JOIN Colours ON Card.Id = Colours.CardId
WHERE Colours.Colour IN (CHARARRAY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cards.Join(_db.Colours,
           x => x.Id,
           z => z.CardId,
           (x, z) => new {x, z}).Where(x => filter.ColourFilter.Contains(x.z.Colour))
           .Select(x => x.x).ToList();
```

The above code was the answer to my question, the `.Join` extension method was used to join the two tables and then the *linq* `.Where` was used to filter on items contained in my *array*.

`cards` is my initial subset of objects and `_db` is my Entity Framework database context.

Comment: @mjwills noted.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the pseudo-code below will help you

```
var colorsArr = new char[];
var db = new MyContext();

from card in db.Cards
join color in db.Colors on card.Id equals color.CardId
where (from ch in colorsArr select ch).Contains(color.Colour)
select new {card, color}
```